# filterstream of StreamR package is not resulting in data from Twitter though it saves some file

Tags: r, twitter

This is my query of streamR package, below query is resulting a message as shown - 
"Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 600 seconds with up to 74 tweets downloaded."

This is saving a file to my local with name - tweets_keyword.json, but there is no data in it.

library(streamR)

library(ROAuth)

filterStream(file.name="tweets_keyword.json", track=c("#liveittobelieveit"), timeout=600, tweets=1000,oauth=my_oauth)

Sorry if I have not followed any rules of this site, I'm new here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As i said, above query is not resulting in any data in the file - tweets_keyword.json, but it says 74 tweets downloaded in the command line. What's the problem, how do I fix this so that data shows up in the file instead of empty file?

Comment: try increasing the timeout value

Comment: I have done that, it is only increasing no of tweets count in the command line message, file is empty as usual. Any other fixes?